# How to change the background color of navigation bar in a modal view?

Tags: ios

I present a modal view when I click a cell in my custom tableview. How to change the background color of navigation bar in a modal view?
For example. I want to change it to black color.The following code do not work in the prepare segue method.

```
[destinationNavController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

or

```
 [[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

or

```
 [destinationNavController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

in the viewDidLoad method of the destination Controller view I write

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

or

```
 [[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

or

```
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];// only change the navigation item text color....
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the right way to present the modal controller and change the nav bar color, write the below code:-

```
[self presentModalViewController:customViewController animated:YES];

customViewController.topViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on ios 7 or later, you need to use the `barTintColor` property of `UINavigationBar`.

Like this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

I only tested this in iOS 11 so far and in my case our app is white but I want to present a fullscreen slide show with black color, but I still wanted a status bar, with white letters and the same black background as my main view

Step 1: make your view background color black.
 XCode in your .xib or storyboard the parents view's background color black (very important step)

Step 2: 
in your view controller that is in charge of this view, add this:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { return .lightContent }
```

This makes the color of the status text to be white. This also works on iPhone X.